# Using multiple and condition in join query

Tags: php, mysql, join, where-clause

I want to join query if the value in a post is not equal to blank and it runs perfectly when the value in both the post value. The problem is when the value is in only one post then `AND` comes before any other second value.  Hope to get the solution. I am using core PHP

```
if(!empty($_POST['agent_wise'])){       
    $agent_wise = $_POST['agent_wise'];
    $queryCondition .= "allusers.sno ='$agent_wise'";
} 

if(!empty($_POST['status_wise'])){      
    $status_wise = $_POST['status_wise'];
    $queryCondition .= " AND st_application.admin_status_crs ='$status_wise'";
}   
if(!empty($_POST['course_wise'])){      
    $course_wise = $_POST['course_wise'];
    $queryCondition .= " AND st_application.prg_name1 ='$course_wise'";
}


$result2 = "SELECT * FROM st_application INNER JOIN allusers on st_application.user_id = allusers.sno where " . $queryCondition . " ";
```

Comment: what error did you get with this query?

Comment: @rajinder if the first condition is unsatisfied the query will fail

Comment: ok. the problem with "AND" keyword. let give you a updated code in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is solution...

```
$flag = 0;
if(!empty($_POST['agent_wise'])){ 
        $flag = 1;    
        $agent_wise = $_POST['agent_wise'];
        $queryCondition .= "allusers.sno ='$agent_wise'";
     } 

if(!empty($_POST['status_wise'])){      
        $status_wise = $_POST['status_wise'];
        if($flag == 1){
        $queryCondition .= " AND st_application.admin_status_crs ='$status_wise'";
        }
      else {
        $queryCondition .= " st_application.admin_status_crs ='$status_wise'";
         $flag = 1;
  }
    }   
    if(!empty($_POST['course_wise'])){      
        $course_wise = $_POST['course_wise'];
       if ($flag == 1){
        $queryCondition .= " AND st_application.prg_name1 ='$course_wise'";
      }
       else {
           $queryCondition .= " st_application.prg_name1 ='$course_wise'";
    }
    }


$result2 = "SELECT * FROM st_application INNER JOIN allusers on st_application.user_id = allusers.sno where " . $queryCondition . " ";
```

Comment: Thank you. Its Done

Comment: can you please help me with this ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52342932/create-multiple-zip-files-with-php

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
if(!empty($_POST['agent_wise'])){      
    $agent_wise = $_POST['agent_wise'];
    $queryCondition .= "allusers.sno ='$agent_wise'";
 } 

if(!empty($_POST['status_wise'])){      
    $status_wise = $_POST['status_wise'];
    $queryCondition .= " AND st_application.admin_status_crs ='$status_wise'";
}   

if(!empty($_POST['course_wise'])){      
    $course_wise = $_POST['course_wise'];
    $queryCondition .= " AND st_application.prg_name1 ='$course_wise'";
}


$queryCondition = trim($queryCondition, 'AND'); 


$result2 = "SELECT * FROM st_application INNER JOIN allusers on st_application.user_id = allusers.sno where " . $queryCondition . " ";
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Hi Rajinder,
can u please help me with this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52342932/create-multiple-zip-files-with-php

Answer (score 0):

The lazy hack is to include an `AND` in the first condition too, and change `WHERE` to `WHERE 1`, but there are smarter and, I suspect, easily searchable ways to solve this. Oh, and also see about sql injection and the importance of prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

Check for empty string before concating 'AND'.

```
$queryCondition .=  (empty($queryCondition) ? "" : " AND ") . 
    "st_application.admin_status_crs ='$status_wise'"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to your problem. One SQL solution and one PHP solution:

**First Solution**

```
if(!empty($_POST['agent_wise'])){       
    $agent_wise = $_POST['agent_wise'];
    $queryCondition .= " AND allusers.sno ='$agent_wise'";
} 

if(!empty($_POST['status_wise'])){      
    $status_wise = $_POST['status_wise'];
    $queryCondition .= " AND st_application.admin_status_crs ='$status_wise'";
}   
if(!empty($_POST['course_wise'])){      
    $course_wise = $_POST['course_wise'];
    $queryCondition .= " AND st_application.prg_name1 ='$course_wise'";
}


$result2 = "SELECT * FROM st_application INNER JOIN allusers on st_application.user_id = allusers.sno where TRUE" . $queryCondition . " ";
```

This works because in WHERE TRUE AND 'something else' the TRUE condition is redundant. The only drawback is that if none of the POSTs are present, you will get ALL records back, since WHERE TRUE always brings back records. But you can easiliy do a check to see all POSTs are present and bail out if not:

```
if (empty($_POST['agent_wise']) && empty($_POST['status_wise']) && empty($_POST['course_wise']) ) exit;
```

**Second Solution**

```
$queryConditionsArray = [];

if(!empty($_POST['agent_wise'])){       
    $agent_wise = $_POST['agent_wise'];
    $queryConditionsArray[] = "allusers.sno ='$agent_wise'";
} 

if(!empty($_POST['status_wise'])){      
    $status_wise = $_POST['status_wise'];
    $queryConditionsArray[] = "st_application.admin_status_crs ='$status_wise'";
}   
if(!empty($_POST['course_wise'])){      
    $course_wise = $_POST['course_wise'];
    $queryConditionsArray[] = "st_application.prg_name1 ='$course_wise'";
}

$queryCondition = implode(' AND ', $queryConditionsArray);

$result2 = "SELECT * FROM st_application INNER JOIN allusers on st_application.user_id = allusers.sno where " . $queryCondition . " ";
```

This works because the **implode** will only insert the word 'AND' between the conditions - not at the start of each condition. Again you will have to check if no POSTs are present because your SQL will fail otherwise.

Personally I prefer the second way, but it depends on the circumstances.